# How to create untrusted user with ssh access

Tags: debian, permissions, user-management

How can I create a user with ssh access but with only read access to their home directory and nothing else?

I created a user and added it to a group but they still can `ls /home/*`.

I'd like to give git read/write access using ssh but I don't want the user to go around a poke at other users directories.

I am using Debian stretch.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the permissions of the user home directories such that only owners have access to those.